# Excel find results not in one array from another

Tags: arrays, excel, compare

Without using VBA, is there any way to find and output the results missing from one array compared to another into cells.

I have two sheets, on Sheet1 is a list of numbers in column B and "N/A" In column J if we are done with them. On Sheet2 is we paste a list of numbers in column B. I need to be able to find the numbers missing from Sheet2 that do not have an "N/A" tag in Sheet1 and output them to column C.

I tried {=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!B:B<>B:B)*(Sheet1!J:J<>"N/A"),0))} but (Sheet1!B:B<>B:B) doesn't seem to be doing what i think it should. I understand that the above formula won't give more than 1 result yet. I would need to add something to eliminate the results already in column C, but one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`Sheet1!B:B<>B:B` compares corresponding cells in two sheets. Unless the numbers appear at the same exact rows in both sheets, your code will not work.

I don't think it is possible to deal with this with array formula, because `Match` doesn't accept an array as its first argument. But you can enter this in C1 and copy and paste to the whole column:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!B:B,0)),IF(Sheet1!J1<>"N/A",Sheet1!B1,""),"")
```

There will be empty cells though.

Answer (score 0):

Full list is an array, say A1:E10, which I will assume you can reference as A1#
Sub list is an array starting at G1:J6, which I will assume you can reference as G1#

You want to see if any of the values in the first column of 'Sub List' don't exist in the first column of 'Full list'

=Let(fulllist,index(A1#,,1), sublist, index(G1#,,1), result, filter(sublist,NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(sublist,fulllist,0)))),result)

obviously, to see which ones DO exist in the full list, you would remove the NOT statement and related brackets.

**Caveat --- this works on newer versions of excel which allow for array spillranges.